# SSH отваливается с Write failed: Broken pipe

Tags: ssh, pipes

До недавнего времени удаленный сервер работал нормально, но теперь если после непродолжительного времени(1-2 мин) оставить окно терминала и не трогать, то затем напечатать удается буквально 2-3 символа, и сервер зависает намертво. Через полминуты появляется надпись Write failed: Broken pipe
Доступ к серверу имел еще один человек, может и он мог как-то нашкодить, но я уже несколько раз ребилдил сервер; ни к чему это не привело, все то же самое.
Пробовал и прописывать строчки в файлы ssh_config и sshd_config, не помогает. 
Какие еще могут быть причины таких проблем с VPS?

Comment: Может в .bashrc или .bash_profile переменная  TMOUT появилась?

Посмотрите, например, [здесь](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/05/tmout-exit-bash-shell-when-no-activity/)

Comment: Я проверил, ее нет, да и неоткуда. Ведь после ребилда все стоит на дефолте

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решилась сменой порта сервера.
Видимо, какая-то из прог юзала тот же порт